pyd file cannot find numpy in python 3.11 and windows 11
I compiled a submodule.pyx file into submodule.cp311-win_amd64.pyd with cython 3.0.8.  Then I used pyInstaller 6.11.0 to make an appx.exe.  But then appx.exe said it cannot find numpy which is imported in submodule.pyx. Any help will be greatly appreciated.  My file structure is as follows.
.
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   └── submodule.pyx
├── README.txt
├── setup.py 
└── appx.py

appx.py is as follows.
from src import submodule   
subObj = submodule.runApp() 

setup.py is as follows.
# setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    name="appx",
    version='1.37.41',
    ext_modules = cythonize(
        [
            Extension("src.submodule", ["src/submodule.pyx"]),
        ],
        build_dir="build_cythonize",
        compiler_directives={
            'language_level' : "3",
            'always_allow_keywords': True,
        }
    ),
    cmdclass=dict(
        build_ext=build_ext
    ),
)

File __init__.py is as follows.  Since I am not sure if pyinstaller can find all the dependencies in submodule.pyd, so I listed all the import statements of all those basic modules in this file.
# Note!  There should be no whatever module variables in CnUtil. 
from __future__ import print_function    # (at top of module)
import sys 

if sys.version_info[0] < 3: # Python 2 and 3:

    #  to execute the file, type in the following command in powershell: 
    #  % python CnTestDragonPackage.py build_ext --inplace
    import future        # pip install future
    import builtins      # pip install future
    import past          # pip install future
    import six           # pip install six

from submodule import runApp 

import numpy
import cv2
import base64
import wx
import os
import string
import random
import math
import copy
import subprocess
import json
import threading
import datetime
import shutil

Then I executed the following commands in sequence in the folder of app.py.
conda activate myCondaEnv311_Windows
python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Then I saw file submodule.cp311-win_amd64.pyd appeared in folder
./src

Then I executed the following command to use pyInstaller for packaging.
pyinstaller --name "appx" --add-data="README.txt:." --add-binary="src/submodule.cp311-win_amd64.pyd:src" appx.py

After this, I saw the file structure expanded as follows.
.
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   └── submodule.pyx
├── build
├── build_cythonize
├── dist
│   └── appx
│       ├── _internal 
│       └── appx.exe
├── README.txt
├── setup.py 
└── appx.py

Then I changed directory to ./dist/appx and typed in appx.exe.
But it aborted with command output:
No module named 'numpy'

Can someone tell me how to do this correctly ?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Are you using the numpy API in any of your .pyx files? This would mean having a cimport numpy as np line, for example.
